# Sum values that are elements in the same tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, tuples, element

I'm selecting data from an sqlite database and creating a dictionary using:

```
self.cur.execute('''SELECT description,quantity from assetTable''')
    assetTuples = self.cur.fetchall()
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in assetTuples:
        dic[k].append(v)
```

This gives me a dictionary that prints as:

```
{'asset1': [11, 25], 'asset2': [6, 5], 'asset3': [88, 11]}
```

How do you sum values that are elements in the same tuple? I want it to end up as:

```
{'asset1': [36], 'asset2': [11], 'asset3': [99]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say, `assetTuples` looks something like this

```
assetTuples = [('asset1', 11), ('asset1', 25), ('asset2', 6), ('asset2', 5), ('asset3', 88), ('asset3', 11)]
```

You can simply iterate and accumulate the values like this

```
result = {}

for k, v in assetTuples:
    result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v

print(result)
# {'asset2': 11, 'asset1': 36, 'asset3': 99}
```

Answer (score 1):

result on new dict:

```
d={'asset1': [11, 25], 'asset2': [6, 5], 'asset3': [88, 11]}
result = {e:[sum(d[e])] for e in d}
```

If you want to update same variable:

```
d.update({e:[sum(d[e])] for e in d})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> assetTuples=[('asset1',11),('asset1',25),('asset2',11),('asset3',99)]
>>> dic=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in assetTuples:
...     if dic[k]==[]:
...        dic[k]=[v]
...     else:
...        dic[k][0]+=v
... 
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'asset2': [11], 'asset3': [99], 'asset1': [36]})
```

Comment: Please follow pep8 convention.

Comment: `for i, v in dic.iteritems(): d[i] = sum(v)` is enough.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay, That way you first create a dictionary then add list items. Thus needs two dictionary traversals, one for creating it and one for adding list items. Here I add list items while building the dictionary itself. Thus saving one dictionary traversal and additional calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
assetDict = {'asset1': [11, 25], 'asset2': [6, 5], 'asset3': [88, 11]}

for key, value in assetDict.iteritems():
    assetDict[key] = sum(value)

print assetDict
# {'asset2': 11, 'asset1': 36, 'asset3': 99}
```